# Inheritance hierarchy for View in Django REST framework

Tags: python, django

Apparently you can only have one level of inheritance when it comes to views using the Django REST framework.

This works:

```
class Foo(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return "hello world"
```

While this does not:

```
class Foo(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return self.bar()

class Bar(Foo):
    def bar(self):
        return "hello world"
```

It appears that this is deliberate, due to the code in as_view()
http://django-rest-framework.org/_modules/views.html

Does anyone know a workaround?

Thanks!

EDIT:
Okay, well I found out I can do:

```
class Foo(View):
    def __init__(self):
        View.__init__(proxy = self)

    def get(self, request):
        return self.proxy.bar()

class Bar(Foo):
    def bar(self):
        return "hello world"
```

But this is not really "acceptable" in the long term.  Does anyone know of a more legitimate way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If this question is still standing, I don't think we have enough information to answer it.

First of all,

```
class Foo(object):
    def get(self):
        return self.bar()

class Bar(Foo):
    def bar(self):
        return "hello world"
```

probably isn't good code in any case, regardless of whether Foo extends django-rest-framework's View class. You are essentially breaking foo.get by assuming it has a bar method, which it doesn't.

```
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.get()
AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'bar'
```

This:

```
>>> bar = Bar()
>>> bar.get()
```

will work. But, you've essentially ruined Foo by writing it this way. At least provide a stub method.

Regardless, you haven't posted your urls.py, so I"m not sure whether you're trying to do Foo.as_view() or Bar.as_view(). I tested it out with djangorestframework.views.View, and, as expected,

```
#urls.py
from testviews.views import Foo, Bar
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', Bar.as_view(), name='home'),
)
```

works fine for me, whereas,

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', Foo.as_view(), name='home'),
)
```

does not for the same reason that the above code doesn't work.